# Quoted string not properly terminated when I try to run my code

Tags: mysql

I get the message:

quoted string not properly terminated when I try to run my code. This is the code:

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(197365, 'Julius', 'Caesar', 2737, ‘M’, 191963, ‘cook’);

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your quot characters are not correct, some of them are `'` which is correct, but others are Unicode `‘` (0x2018) characters which is incorrect.

This usually happens when you copy/paste SQLs from web sites, PDFs or Word documents.

Comment: I thought that could be the reason, but I tried typing it in manually and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you write whole query into a clean query window? There could be some garbage characters somewhere else (for example 0xA0 looks exactly same as `space` char but it actually not and could lead an error). 

Try also selecting those values: `select 197365, 'Julius', 'Caesar', 2737, 'M', 191963, 'cook'`, I tested on my local and it runs well.

Comment: I was never able to get working with command line but I had no issues with mysql workbench.

Comment: Which OS you are on? I still looks a character encoding issue to me, you CLI could be problematic, can you try with `bash` or another OS?